# using mustache with json from remote api url

Tags: json, mustache

mustache documentation describes using local typed json source eg like mustache demo linked below ..

http://mustache.github.com/#demo

however mustache documentation does not describe syntax for using remote linked json source.

i was able to successfully copy and paste the json source i get from api into the mustache demo and modify the mustache template to get desired results ok

just don't know how to reference remote json results from api at url .. fwiw, i am getting my json results from this url

GET http://www.car2go.com/api/v2.0/vehicles?loc=austin&format=json

perhaps i might have to save json results locally, then read them, but still have issue of how to get mustache to look at remote file not typed json source .. any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Let me see if I understood your question correctly. You want the json that is to be used by mustache from a remote api and template your markup on the client side?

if that is the case then you could do something as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/api/v2.0/vehicles",
  data: {loc:'austin',format:'json'},
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  success: templateAndRender
});

function templateAndRender(jsonResponse)
{
  var html=Mustache.to_html("yourTemplate",jsonResponse);
  //code yo insert html Eg. $('selector').html(html);
}
```

Note the ajax request needs to be form the same domain if its cross-domain request you need to use jsonp

Comment: So I am running into the same issues is the OP. I unfortunately cannot post, I am using vanilla JS instead of jQuery to fetch my JSON SharePoint List Data. How can I then populated it to my mustache template? I am getting no errors in console, but nothing is happening.